# How to display FontAwsome text as Drawable Left in Edit Text

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any other way apart from using a Text View and an Edit text widgets together inside Linear Layout and applying the fontawsome Unicode to the Text View.

[image: Design]

Comment: you need to try [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2460) , [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1843)

Answer (score 1):

In strings.xml file create a string and set its value the name of the font awesom icon name example :

```
<string name="fa fa-cloud">cloud</string>
```

Now in xml file where your edittext is
just include this line 
android:drawableLeft=@string/cloud 
This will set the icon in ur edit text.